# how to set text to dynamically create edittext with string id

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="testEditText " type="id"/>
</resources>

final EditText testEditText = new EditText(getActivity());
testEditText.setId(R.id.testEditText);
```

I created a edittext dynamically but i cannot set text into it from another function.

```
EditText testEditText= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.testEditText);
```

i tried to initialize it but it always return null.

Is there any way i can set and get value of testedittext from different function

Comment: findViewById() is expensive, why not just keep a reference to the EditText and pass that along since you are dynamically creating it?

Comment: Just curious, have you added the view to your layout?

Comment: yea passing it would work but i dont want it pass just was looking to gettext without passing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set any integer value in `setId()`. you have to set some unique values to differentiate with other dynamically created views.

so give like this.

```
testEditText.setId(1);
```

so you can use this id for onClickListner , onTouchListner etc...

Answer (score 0):

above oncrtae

```
EditText test;
```

in on create

```
test = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.testEditText);

test.setText("bla bla");
```